# Use list in mongodb C driver

Tags: mongodb, bson, mongodb-c

Here's the structure part of my collection :

```
{
   ...
   likes: ['6a6ca923517f304900badd98','6a6ca923517f304900badd99','...'],
   ...
}
```

Which method could you advise me to retrieve the list of values in the "likes" field with C lib please ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a working MongoDB C driver, but this should help get you started. Also, the docs should help you ([here](http://api.mongodb.org/c/current/tutorial.html)).

```
bson_iterator i[1], sub[i];
bson_type type;
const char * key;
const char * value;

// do query, get cursor

while(mongo_cursor_next(cursor) == MONGO_OK) {
    // look for the "likes" field
    if( bson_find( iterator, bson, "likes" )) {
        // need to iterate through the elements of the array
        bson_iterator_subiterator( iterator, sub );

        // then iterate using "sub", until returns a BSON_EOO
        while (BSON_EOO != bson_iterator_next( sub )) {
            key = bson_iterator_key( sub );
            // if it's a string...
            value = bson_iterator_string( sub );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my post with a new question ! Can you help me ?

Comment: @JohnS-that's not really how StackOverflow works. :(  Please try it on your own and post where you've gotten stuck in a new question. I'd imagine you'd use `bson_find` on the `sub` for `"name"`.